# Passing method result as a query parameter in another method in java

Tags: java, hibernate

I am quite new to java and i would like to use the result of a private method as a parameter in another method in the same class.

```
private String getMaxDate() {
    String QryMaxDate = "SELECT Max(NAV_DATE) as maxdate FROM NAVS  WHERE CONFIRMD IS NOT NULL AND SECURITY_CODE <> '002'";
    try {
        em = LocalEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        return em.createNativeQuery(QryMaxDate).getSingleResult().toString();

    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

and the method I intend to use the result from above method is as below.

```
public List<Object[]> get_account_balance(String MemberNo) {

    System.out.println("****************Getting account Balance*****");
    //example query 
    String balance  = "SELECT * FROM trans WHERE trans_date = :max  AND member_no = :member_no";
    try {
        String maxDate = getMaxDate();

       System.out.println(maxDate);

        em = LocalEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        return em.createNativeQuery(balance)
                .setParameter("max", maxDate)
                .setParameter("member_no", MemberNo)
                .getResultList();

    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: You should be able to simply do `.setParameter("max", getMaxDate())`

Comment: you already do, didn't you see it?

Comment: They are in same class. You should able to call it like any regular method which you already did.

Comment: Zircon .setParameter("max", getMaxDate()) worked

Comment: I had no confidence in what I had done.. `.setParameter("max", getMaxDate())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the result of getMaxDate() to a String, like this:

```
String result = getMaxDate();
```

And then use result in get_account_balance(), like this:

```
get_account_balance(result)
```

If you are having issues passing the result as an argument, you just need to change the signature of the method, like this:

```
get_account_balance(String MemberNo, String result)
```

You can also simply call getMaxDate() from within the method, like this:

```
.setParameter("max", getMaxDate())
```

I think you are looking for that.

Comment: Excellent! Please remember to accept the answer. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

As long as each method is in the same class, the `public` method can access the `private` method. Your line `String maxDate = getMaxDate();` should be fine.